# unwanted keys in JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

hi i am creating a JSON object after executing a loop. the problem is the JSON object have additional keys. i don't want that keys. that keys are generated by me. for arraigning the json according my requirement. this is code i am using for create my JSON object

```
 var bankdata = data;
    var updatebankdata = {}
    for (var key in bankdata) {
        var id = +key.substr(key.length - 1);

        if (isNaN(id)) {
            updatebankdata[0] = updatebankdata[0] || {};
            updatebankdata[0][key] = bankdata[key];
        } else {
            var uniqid=$("#bankaccount"+id).attr("uniq_id");
            updatebankdata[id] = updatebankdata[id] || {};
            var field = key.substring(0, key.length - 1);
            updatebankdata[id][field] = bankdata[key];
            updatebankdata[id]["uniquid"] = uniquid;
        }
    }
    return updatebankdata;
}
```

my bank data is like

> {bankname1: "new", micrcode1: "mkkk", comments1: "commentsfvfdv", bankname2: "bankfgname", micrcode2: "micrfgcode"…}

i want to change it into  like this way

> [{bankname1: "new", micrcode1: "mkkk", comments1:
>   "commentsfvfdv"},{bankname2: "bankfgname", micrcode2: "micrfgcode"}]

but still it getting like this .its not good

> {"0":{bankname1: "new", micrcode1: "mkkk", comments1:
>
> > "commentsfvfdv"},"1":{bankname2: "bankfgname", micrcode2: "micrfgcode"}

what is the mistake in my code?

Comment: You are using a PHP dictionary not an array, which gets translated to a JSON dictionary. Rather than calling `updatebankdata[id]` create objects and them push them to the array using [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an array instead of an object. Like so:

```
   function func(data) {
       var bankdata = data;
       var updatebankdata = [];  // ARRAY instead of Object
       for (var key in bankdata) {
           var id = +key.substr(key.length - 1);

           if (isNaN(id)) {
               updatebankdata[0] = updatebankdata[0] || {};
               updatebankdata[0][key] = bankdata[key];
           } else {
               var uniqid=$("#bankaccount"+id).attr("uniq_id");
               updatebankdata[id] = updatebankdata[id] || {};
               var field = key.substring(0, key.length - 1);
               updatebankdata[id][field] = bankdata[key];
               updatebankdata[id]["uniquid"] = uniqid;  // CHANGED to "uniqid" to match variable declaration above, not the key on the left is still "uniquid"
           }
       }
       return updatebankdata;
   }
```

Then you can get result like:

```
JSON.stringify(func({name: 'someval', val: 123}));
"[{"name":"someval","val":123}]"
```

Comment: but still iam getting object like [undefined × 2, Object] how can i solve this?

Comment: Probably happening because of typo. uniquid is not defined, but instead uniqid is... I'll update the snippet I posted.

Comment: You could just filter undefined values like: return updatebankdata.filter(function(v) { if (v) { return v } });

Answer (score 0):

assign

`var updatebankdata = [];`

then push your object to array like this

`updatebankdata.push(yourObject)`